# Mellin-Barnes (MB) integrals and hypergeometic functions

Tags: mathematical-physics, integration

I'm trying to understand a step in [arXiv:1104.2661](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2661). Equation 3.4 reads,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\Gamma(2\epsilon)}\int_{-i\infty}^{i\infty}\frac{d\omega}{2i\pi}\frac{(-t)^\omega}{(-s)^{2-\epsilon+\omega}}\Gamma^2(\omega+1)\Gamma(2-\epsilon+\omega)\Gamma(-\omega)\Gamma^2(\epsilon-1-\omega). \tag{3.4}
\end{equation}
Then, by taking the poles $\omega=\epsilon-2-n$ the result reads,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\Gamma(\epsilon)^2\Gamma(1-\epsilon)^2}{\Gamma(2\epsilon)\Gamma(2-\epsilon)}(-t)^{\epsilon-2}\ _2F_1(1,1,2-\epsilon,-\frac{s}{t}). \tag{3.5}
\end{equation}
The question is very simple. The residue theorem give the following result,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \Gamma(\epsilon-1-n)^2\Gamma(n+2-\epsilon)(-1)^nn!\frac{(-t)^{\epsilon-2-n}}{(-s)^{-n}}.
\end{equation}
The definition of the hypergeometric reads,
\begin{equation}
_2F_1(a,b,c,z)=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(a+n)\Gamma(b+n)}{\Gamma(c+n)}\frac{z^n}{n!}.
\end{equation}
I don't see what I have to do in order to obtain the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Recall that the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) $\Gamma(z)$ has poles at non-positive integers $z\in -\mathbb{N}_0$.
2. Use Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) to replace the factor 
   $$ \Gamma(\omega+1)^2\Gamma(-\omega) ~=~ \frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi\omega)} \frac{1}{\Gamma(-\omega)} $$
   in eq. (3.4).
3. Now the only simple poles in the negative $\omega$ halfplane of the rewritten integrand (3.4) come from the $\Gamma(2-\epsilon+\omega)$ function.
4. Closed the integration contour in the negative $\omega$ halfplane, and perform the contour integral via the [residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).
5. Use Euler's reflection formula again to get the factor $\Gamma(\epsilon)^2\Gamma(1-\epsilon)^2$ in eq. (3.5).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually the problem was to handle the reflection formula, but I find a nicer form of it which is easier to handle.\begin{equation}\frac{\Gamma(\epsilon-n)}{\Gamma(1+\epsilon)}=(-1)^{n-1}\Gamma(-\epsilon)/\Gamma(n+1-\epsilon)\end{equation}